# Error Code:A2206 missing operator in expression visual studio 2022 masm64

Tags: visual-studio-2022, masm, masm64

hello how can i fix error A2206 missing operator in expression every line have rel

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   A2206   missing operator in expression  OpenParrot  C:\Files\Projects\OpenParrot\OpenParrot\src\hooks.asm   7

```
extern whereRenderShape:proc
extern whereRenderText:proc
extern ratio:proc

.code
implOfRenderShape proc
    movss xmm11, [rel ratio]
    movss dword ptr [rbp+8h], xmm11

    mov rax, [rel whereRenderShape]
    add rax, 15
    jmp rax
implOfRenderShape endp

implOfRenderText proc
    movss xmm14, [rel ratio]
    movss dword ptr [rbp-28h], xmm14
    movss dword ptr [rbp-18h], xmm12

    mov rax, [rel whereRenderText]
    add rax, 12
    jmp rax
implOfRenderText endp

end
```

Comment: Are you trying to translate some NASM code? Because I didn't think MASM had a `rel` operator (or any other method of explicitly specifying `rip`-relative addressing). Have you tried just removing all the occurences of `rel`?